# How can one return 400 status code with DRF APIView get method and ModelSerializer?

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework, http-status-codes

I have the following code (for the endpoint /things/{id}/permission-to-do/
**views.py**

```
class PermissionsToDo(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
        thing_id = kwargs.get('pk')
        thing = Thing.objects.filter(pk=thing_id,is_active=True)
        serializer = serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(thing[0],context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def _can_do(self, thing):
        return thing.can_be_done_by(self.context['request'].user)

    can_do = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_can_do')

    class Meta:
        model = Thing.objects.filter
        fields = ('can_do',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'can_do': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

The `thing.can_be_done_by(user)` method returns a Boolean. This works fine with a correct request but I want to add a way to validate the request and send appropriate status code for client errors, such as `status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`

My idea was to just add in **views.py** a:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    return Response(SOMETHING?,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

if I evaluate `serializer.is_valid()` I obtain an error message saying:

```
'Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was '
AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.
```

if I change the line:

```
serializer = serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(thing[0],context={'request': request})
```

into:

```
serializer = serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(data=thing[0],context={'request': request})
```

but then, I get an error suggesting the I should be passing a dictionary as data and not an object. but then I'm not sure how to implement the `validate` method and how to change the `_can_do` method to get it to work.

Any idea?

Thanks for your time if you have some to spare!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.validate()` method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values. It should raise a ValidationError if necessary, or just return the validated values.
One of the ways you can achieve this is to convert the `model object` to a `dict`. So try the following snippet,

```
class PermissionsToDo(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        thing_id = kwargs.get('pk')
        thing = Thing.objects.filter(pk=thing_id, is_active=True)
        serializer = serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(data=thing[0].__dict__, context={'request': request})  # Change is here <<<<
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(SOMETHING?, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

*My suggestion*
If you are serializing the object from DB, most of the time it won't raise any validation error. I would suggest that, try to show error message if `thing` object become a `empty queryset`.So,

```
class PermissionsToDo(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        thing_id = kwargs.get('pk')
        try:
            serializer = serializers.GetDoPermissionSerializer(Thing.objects.get(id=thing_id), context={'request': request})
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Thing.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(data="object not found", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So basically you say it's not common practice to write something like this since this error shouldn't occur?

Comment: Can I ask one thing? At which situation you need to return a `400` error ?

Comment: Empty queryset or request for an id with no existing Thing for that id

Comment: Do I worry too much?

Comment: I think `object.__dict__` will do a small amount of `sql query` that would harm your performance if large number request comes per second. So I would recommend you to use `view` in the **My suggestion** section. (I think that would satisfy your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

I used your "suggestion" to the exception that I had to modify the last line. I replaced:

`return Response(data="object not found", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`

by :

`return Response("object not found", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`

or I get the following error:
`SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`